# Migrating to the Netherlands as a freelancer

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands

I'm a citizen of the Russian Federation. I'm thinking of moving to the Netherlands. I've seen the skilled migrant program, it's pretty cool. But lately I've been thinking of moving to freelance completely, as I don't want to work as an office worker. I want more freedom instead.

I've joined TopTal (https://toptal.com) recently and I think I can really earn enough money to live there. The thing is, can I apply for a visa/residence permit as a freelancer without getting a job offer, so I'd be able to work for myself only? And if so, where can I find more info about that?